# Apache - Add Cache-Control header if not already added

Tags: apache, caching, http-headers, cache-control

In Apache, how can I set a *Response* Header only if it is not already set by the CGI application?

I need a way to automatically add the `Cache-Control` header to static content on my website, but I want the CGI application to be able to specify its own `Cache-Control` header too.

`SetEnvIf` will not work for this purpose because it only matches *Request* Headers.

Is there some way to conditionally / optionally set a header if it is not already set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Configure Apache to append the value of empty string (`""`) to the `Cache-Control` header to ensure the header is **always** included in the response.

2) Configure Apache to set the `Cache-Control` header only if it's **still** set to empty string.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|ico|flv|gif|jpeg|jpg|js|pdf|png|swf)$">
  Header append Cache-Control ""
  Header edit Cache-Control "^[, ]*$" "max-age=1800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```